# Where does ArcGIS persist shared AddIn folder configuration

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in

We want to rollout our customized ArcGIS AddIns enterprise wide. Therefore the esriAddinfiles are stored on a shared folder on the network. ArcGIS does automatically install those (and any updates) if you configure the shared folder in the AddIn Manager. This is described in http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Sharing_add_ins/0001000009tm000000/ under "share AddIns on a network"

I wonder if it is possible to configure this folder centralized, like a registry key where it is to set. But I already put a registry tracker on ArcMap to find out where this could be done and found .... nothing. It seems that this is persisted elsewhere.

Anybody has an idea, where I can configure the ArcGIS AddIn shared folder without letting my enterprise end users do it for me (hey, at least I'm sysadmin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this link you can indeed do that in the registry.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Advanced_add_in_concepts/0001000004n7000000/

According to the screenshot on the bottom of that page, and at version 10.0, you'd go to:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ESRI\Desktop10.0\Settings\AddInFolders

Comment: Thanks, thats it! Wonder why I didn't see that in the docs... interestingly these Registry Keys aren't created when you use AddIn Manager, and if you create the keys in the registry the paths you defined in AddIn Manager dissapear. So it's more like a real all or nothing admin function, but at least it does what it should do.

Comment: Have you guys actually ever discovered where ArcMap is storing the addin paths if you do use the Option tab in Add-In Manager.  We need to know how to find this programatically.

Comment: Its ok I found it now - for anyone else wanting to know it's in an XML doc in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.x (Win 7)