# ArcMap addin well-known folder not saved in mxd

Tags: arcgis-desktop, add-in, windows-8

We have a mix of Win7 and Win8 computers, with ArcGis 10.2.1

On the Win7 computers, under Add-In Manager > Options tab, we can add a well-known folder to the box "Search for additional Add-Ins in these folders".  This path is retained by ArcMap, (possibly in the Normal.mxt since it is present in a blank ArcMap doc, before opening an mxd).

This path is not retained on Win8 machines.

Anyone encountered and solved this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem on a 8.1 machine.

Comment: I solved it by a total reinstall of ArcGIS, was a bit drastic but worked...

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Your "bump" prompted me to check again. When I posted the question we had 2 Win8 users and both had this problem -- but in the last few months first one machine, then the other, resolved itself.  A 3rd person got a Win8 box recently and has not had that problem. None of them reinstalled ArcMap. This suggests to me that an OS update fixed things for us.  Glad the reinstall worked though.  Just wanted to add more data in case anyone else is looking for answers.

Comment: Further info:  We got two newly-built, clean Win 10 computers with ArcGIS 10.2.  They both refused to retain the Well-Known Folder path for about one work week. Then they started behaving with no intervention from us, and have been trouble-free for three months.

Comment: As recenty noted  [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119449/where-does-arcgis-persist-shared-addin-folder-configuration) _italic_ **bold** `code`. there is an xml which points to the well-known folder:  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.x